# template function for conditional dereference

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I don't know why there's no such function in std (at least I didn't find one). I need a conditional template function to return a reference to an object of `T`. `T` might be passed as a pointer or a smart pointer or by reference:

```
template <typename T>
void do_foo(T &t)
{
   auto &&res = dereference(t).foo();
}
```

So I wrote this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace eld::traits
{
    template<typename T>
    struct is_pointer_like : std::is_pointer<T>
    {
        using value_type = T;
    };

    template<typename T, typename DeleterT>
    struct is_pointer_like<std::unique_ptr<T, DeleterT>> : std::true_type
    {
        using value_type = T;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct is_pointer_like<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type
    {
        using value_type = T;
    };

    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename T, bool /*false*/ = is_pointer_like<T>::value>
        struct dereference
        {
            constexpr explicit dereference(T &t)   //
              : value(t)
            {
            }

            T &value;
        };

        template<typename PtrT>
        struct dereference<PtrT, true>
        {
            constexpr explicit dereference(PtrT &ptrT)
                : value(*ptrT)
            {}

            typename is_pointer_like<PtrT>::value_type &value;
        };
    }   // namespace detail

    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto& dereference(T &t)
    {
        return detail::dereference<std::decay_t<T>>(t).value;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr const auto& dereference(const T &t)
    {
        return detail::dereference<const std::decay_t<T>>(t).value;
    }

}   // namespace eld::traits
```

---

This code does not support the concept of shared pointer though. `dereference` does not increment a counter, so using an obtained reference is dangerous. Because when `std::shared_ptr` is used the user is expected to hold a copy of it (like with `std::weak_ptr`).
Taking it into an account I suppose using `dereference` as a function is a wrong approach. I think that `dereference` should be a persistent object if I expect it to support a concept of sharable ownership.

```
template <typename T>
void so_stuff(T &t)
{
   dereference derefT{t};
   auto &refT = derefT.value();
   auto &&res = refT.foo();
}
```

However, this becomes convoluted in use.

---

Also, I feel like using `is_pointer_like` is redundant. Maybe I am better of just implementing `dereference` with SFINAE customizations for raw and smart pointers.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for this a bit more?  I'm guessing that it's a helper for other templates which you want to use with pointer-like types, but at some point there has to be some invocation, so is this just a matter of saving someone a `*` somewhere in the code?

Comment: @TobySpeight you are correct, it is a utility to be used within a tempate function. As you can see  from an example `void do_stuff`, I need to invoke a member function of T. But I don't want to limit T to be either a reference or a pointer. Because member invokation for the latter requires dereferencing. So template for a pointer would not compile for a reference. Hence I want an adapter that will access the member and compile in both cases.

Comment: Why not call `do_stuff(*foo)` when using with a pointer?  (I'm assuming that's a function similar to `so_stuff()` in the question)  Is it because `foo` has come from dereferencing an iterator or something, where the caller can't know whether it needs to dereference for itself?  I'm asking because that might make a difference to the object-lifetime concerns you mentioned.

Comment: @TobySpeight `the caller can't know whether it needs to dereference for itself` exactly. In case you have a complex template logic and you assume that at *some* point you get an object which might be a pointer, or not. It will facilitate, for example, modification of containers. You would be able to change value type to be a pointer, without changing the logic (adding or removing dereferencing)

Comment: I think that what you want is somewhere buried in here: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/print_using.h .. but no time to extract it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It is probably a bad idea

Your `dereference()` will even work if you don't give it a pointer-like type:

```
int foo = 42;
std::cout << eld::traits::dereference(foo) << '\n';
```

That prints out 42. Maybe it's still simple when we deal with (a pointer to) an `int`, but what if we have a pointer to a pointer? Do you want the first pointer or the second pointer? Or dereference all the way until we get a non-pointer value? It's not even that far-fetched: what if we have a function that that operates on an iterator, and the iterator may or may not be passed via a pointer, but the iterator itself could be just a plain pointer (like `std::begin()` on a C-style array)?

It would really be much better if you put the burden of dereferencing on the caller, as the caller knows best what to do.

Perhaps as a compromise, assuming we want a `T` but it might be passed as `T&`, `T*` or `std::smart_ptr<T>`, you could change `dereference()` so that you have to provide the expected *value* type `T` as a template parameter.

## About supporting `std::shared_ptr`

> This code does not support the concept of shared pointer though. `dereference` does not increment a counter, so using an obtained reference is dangerous.

If you want to do call `derefence()` on a `std::shared_ptr`, I would not worry about it. Your `derefence()` returns a reference, so it's already required that you should keep the original object alive for the duration you are using the reference you got. This is no different from dereferencing or calling `get()` on a `std::shared_ptr` itself.

## It does not work on raw pointers

Surprisingly, while your code works fine with smart pointers, it doesn't work with raw pointers. The problem is that the first `is_pointer_like` version doesn't actually remove the pointer from `T`. That's easy to fix:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_pointer_like : std::is_pointer<T>
{
    using value_type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
};
```

## It doesn't work with temporary `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`s

The following doesn't work either:

```
std::cout << eld::traits::dereference(std::make_unique<int>(42)) << '\n';
```

Even though it works if you pass in a named `std::unique_ptr` variable. The reason is that while you correctly handle `const` in the function `dereference()`, you are missing specializations of `is_pointer_type` that handle `const std::unique_ptr` and `const std::shared_ptr`. You have to add:

```
template<typename T, typename DeleterT>
struct is_pointer_like<const std::unique_ptr<T, DeleterT>> : std::true_type
{
    using value_type = const T;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_pointer_like<const std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type
{
    using value_type = const T;
};
```

Adding a test suite would be helpful in finding these kinds of problems.

## Simplifying the code

One issue at the moment is that you have to explicitly handle both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, and `const` and non-`const` versions of both, duplicating a lot of code. With SFINAE or C++20 concepts, it might be possible to make an `is_pointer_like` that handles both smart pointers in the same way, and might even support other smart point types that have the same interface. In particular, both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` have a member type `element_type`, and a member function `get()`. It would then also work with the deprecated  `std::auto_ptr`. Ideally it looks like:

```
template<typename T>
requires is_smart_pointer_like<T>
struct is_pointer_like<T> : std::true_type
{
    // Deduce the value type such that const is propagated
    using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T&>())>;
};
```

Then the trick is just to implement the concept `is_smart_pointer_like`.
But note that there is nothing in the body that uses `element_type` or `get()`, it only needs `T` to be dereferencable. So perhaps you could even just check for that, as it will then also work for regular pointers, but on the other hand this might match more types than you like. For example, it would then match iterators.